# msys-1.0.dll is out of date

Tags: heroku, git-bash

I had Git Bash installed previously for working against Cloudbees and after downloading the Heroku Toolbelt my Git Bash is giving me the following error...

```
msys-1.0.dll is out of date
```

Is there something I need to update or has the installation upset an ENV variable?

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: checkout https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/issues/21